# In a Rails Migration (MySQL), can you specify what position a new column should be?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

If I'm adding a column via MySQL, I can specify where in the table that column will be using the AFTER modifier. But if I do the add_column via a Rails migration, the column will be created at the end of the table.

Is there any functionality for rails migrations to specify the position of an added column?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is now possible in Rails 2.3.6+ by passing the :after parameter

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3286-patch-add-support-for-mysql-column-positioning-to-migrations

To everyone that doesn't see the advantage in having this feature: do you never look at your database outside of the ORM?  If I'm viewing in any sort of UI, I like having things like foreign keys, status columns, flags, etc, all grouped together.  This doesn't impact the application, but definitely speeds up my ability to review data.

Comment: Thanks for giving a valid reason for caring about the column order. I really didn't get it until I read your answer. If I look at the db outside the ORM that usually means the SQL command-line console or a UI where I can shuffle the columns around as I like. Didn't think about these new-fangled web UI things. :-)

Comment: Any idea if SQLite supports :after option?
Can't get it working in neither change_column nor add_column

Comment: Besides, eg, `:after => :id`, you can also say `:first => true` to insert it as the first column.

Comment: If you're wondering why this doesn't work for migrations run on PostgreSQL, it's because [MySQL supports AFTER as an ADD COLUMN option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) and [PostgreSQL doesn't](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)

Answer (score 33):

Sure you can.

- Short answer:

  ```
  add_column :users, :gender, :string, :after => :column_name
  ```
- Long answer:

Here is an example, let's say you want to add a column called "**gender**" after column "**username**" to "**users**" table.

1. Type `rails g migration AddGenderToUser gender:string`
2. Add "**after => :username**" in migration that was created so it looks like this:

   ```
   class AddSlugToDictionary < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_column :users, :gender, :string, :after => :username
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Could you please add a link to the official documentation?

Answer (score 8):

I created a patch that adds this additional functionality to the ActiveRecord Mysql adapter. It works for master and 2-3-stable.

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3286-patch-add-support-for-mysql-column-positioning-to-migrations

It might be mysql specific, but it doesn't make your migrations any less portable (other adapters would just ignore the extra positioning options).

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be a position option for the `add_column` method in migrations.  But migrations support executing literal SQL.  I'm no Rails developer, but something like the following:

```
class AddColumnAfterOtherColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name INTEGER 
      AFTER other_column"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :table_name, :column_name
  end
end
```

Comment: yup, this is what I do for my application that uses and older version of rails.

Comment: @Ravistm Not surprising, since I answered this in 2008 — before Rails 1.0! Feel free to post your own answer that works with Rails 5.2.

Comment: i gave it a try with miner tweet which was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way within Rails to specify the position of a column. In fact, I think it's only coincidental (and therefore not to be relied on) that columns are created in the order they are named in a migration.

The order of columns within a table is almost relevant and should be so: the common "reason" given is to be able to see a particular subset when executing a "SELECT *", but that's really not a good reason.

Any other reason is probably a design smell, but I'd love to know a valid reason why I'm wrong!

On some platforms, there is a (miniscule) space and performance saving to be obtained by putting the columns with the highest probability of being NULL to the end (because the DMBS will not use any disk space for "trailing" NULL values, but I think you'd have to be running on 1980's hardware to notice.

Comment: It's not coincidental, it's standard SQL behavior that ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN adds the column as the last ordinal position in the table.  MySQL's "AFTER" syntax is an extension to standard SQL.

Comment: ANSI standard? Or de facto? Not quibbling, just curious.

Comment: I'm going by the book "SQL-99 Complete, Really" which describes it as ANSI standard behavior that additional columns are added as the rightmost column in a table.