# how to change the position of a new column in rails 3.x migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a migration that simply adds a new column, but I want it to be added before the created_at and updated_at columns, is there a way to specify in which position the new column is created ?

I searched and only found someone saying to use the :after option in add_column, but it doesn't do anything. then I looked in the rails api docs and found no such option.

Comment: Why does it matter?
I don't know anything about an :after option but if you are still in development and you don't have a problem with losing the data stored in your tables, you could always drop that table, and create it from scratch with all the attributes, without needing a migration to add certain columns.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does that have any impact on smth other than visual readability of the table?

Comment: I want it for better visual readability of the table, but while searching for a solution I found some blog post about performance effects

Comment: @GalBen-Haim, can you share a link to the blog post?

Comment: here you go - http://explainextended.com/2009/05/21/choosing-column-order/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After option works well for me

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :type, :after => :column_name
```

Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371796/in-a-rails-migration-mysql-can-you-specify-what-position-a-new-column-should).

Comment: I tried the :after option and both in db/schema.rb and sqlitebrowser I see no difference. (ofcourse after resetting the db and running migrations)
my development environment is rails 3.2.1 and sqlite

Comment: Seems so, are you using Postgres? Try raw SQL in migration

Comment: i'm using sqlite for development, production will probably be postgres on heroku

Comment: Just to confirm, yes, the :after option only works against a MySQL DB. For some reason the Postgres adapter was never updated to support this (as of Rails 3.2.13)

Comment: Rails 4 still doesn't support :after for Postgres.

Comment: This is not Rail's omission, PG doesn't allow this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3277

Answer (score 4):

From my research, the `:after` option does not work for **SQLite** or **Postgres**, as these DBMSs do not allow such operation. However, the option works for **MySQL**.

References:

1. SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html - this basically
   tells you to create a new table with correct column ordering, then
   copy data over.
2. Postgres: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position