# schema fields ordering on a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

it is possible to tell rails to keep id columns at the top of the schema and timepstamps at the bottom, when adding some fields to a table through a migration?

What I want is to have always this fields in the same position when playing with rails on the console, I know it's possible to reorder them in schema.rb and reload it but I'm looking for a cleaner approach suitable for production environments too.

thank you

Comment: Order of columns shouldn't matter. If it does, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'll quote martin-dempesy: seeing data in an organized fashion is useful while reviewing data through any DB UI (we know it doesn't affect speed or performance).

Comment: Some DB UIs allow reordering of the columns easily. It's drag and drop on Navicat.

Answer (score 5):

You can something like this (probably currently in Mysql only) from Rails 2.3.6+:

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type, after: :other_column_name
```

or

```
change_table :the_table do |t|
  t.column_type :column_name, after: :other_column_name
end
```

Sources:
- [In a Rails Migration (MySQL), can you specify what position a new column should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371796/in-a-rails-migration-mysql-can-you-specify-what-position-a-new-column-should)
- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3286-patch-add-support-for-mysql-column-positioning-to-migrations

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in the [fix-db-schema-conflicts](https://github.com/jakeonrails/fix-db-schema-conflicts) gem which automatically sorts columns alphabetically while generating the `db/schema.rb` file.

Timestamps would not necessarily be last in the list, but the schema will not rely on the order in which columns were added (by migrations).

Comment: I think for most rails apps, the above gem works. There are some edge cases to consider if you use the `select_all` method https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all and use the columns/rows method.

If you wrote good code you likely either didn't use that method, or used select_all with `to_hash` conversion which negates order issues. Be careful using this gem if you have a legacy app which may have order dependency issues.